# How can I say for definite that an equation in more than two variables is not an exact differential?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

As far as I understand, an equation of the form $$M_1\ dx + M_2\ dy = 0$$ (where $M_i$ are functions in $x$ and $y$) is an exact differential if it is in effect an expression of the total differential of some function $Q$, and to confirm this we need to show that $M_1=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ and $M_2=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}$ by showing $$\frac{\partial M_1}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial M_2}{\partial x}$$
If, however, a problem has several constraints $f_i (x, y, z)$ but one of these equations takes the form above with no $dz$ term, is that fact on its own enough to say that the constraint in question is not an exact differential as long as at least one of the other coefficients $M_i$ contains $z$ so that:

1. the partial derivative of $M_i$ with respect to $z$ is not zero hence the test of equality of the partial derivatives does not hold, and
2. because $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z}=0$ no integrating factor can be found as it will always be multiplied by $0$?